# Why I can not use this expression (int, list) in code

Tags: python

I have a problem with (int, list):

```py
def randint_sum_equal_to(sum_value: int, n: int, lower: (int, list) = 0, upper: (int,list) = None):

"Tuple expression not allowed in type annotation Use Tuple[T1, ..., Tn] to indicate a tuple type or Union[T1, T2] to indicate a union type"
```

thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried using `Tuple[int, list]` instead like the error states?

Comment: On modern Python ([3.9 and higher](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections)), `tuple[int, list]` would also work (the built-in classes themselves support genericizing, without relying on `typing` classes).

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the standard typing library.

```
from typing import Tuple

...
def randint_sum_equal_to(sum_value: int, n: int, lower: Tuple[int, list] = 0, upper: Tuple[int, list] = None):
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason it's forbidden is that it is too ambiguous. As the error message notes, people typing such an expression *might* mean it's a `tuple` of an `int` and a `list`, or they *might* mean it's *either* an `int` or a `list`.

To avoid the ambiguity, you need to specify:

- If it's intended to be a `tuple`, on any type-annotation friendly version of Python you can import `Tuple` from the `typing` module and use `Tuple[int, list]`. On Python 3.9 and higher, you can avoid the import and just use `tuple[int, list]`.
- If it's intended to mean `int` *or* `list`, on any type-annotation friendly version of Python you can import `Union` from the `typing` module and use `Union[int, list]`. On Python 3.10 and higher, you can avoid the import and just use `int | list`.